# My web service takes a list of Guids as an argument, but the generated reference wants an observable collection

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I'm kind of confused here. I have a WCF web service

```
<OperationContract()>
Function StartStep(ByVal Key As Guid, WorkOrders As List(Of Guid), UserUID As Guid, Comment As String) As Boolean
```

But when I generate my web reference on my client, `WorkOrders` comes out as an observableCollection. I created a few new web services and all of the lists are doing that. A list is a fairly common data type, I assumed it would be handled properly by WCF.. could this be because I have another function that returns an ObservableCollection and that's screwing something up? Would I have to use a KnownType or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Advanced" tab of the "Add Service Reference" dialog, you get to say how you want collections handled on the client. I guess you have it set to default to ObservableCollection, but you can select List.

---

Neither "List", nor "ObservableCollection", nor any other .NET type are transferred over the wire. In all cases, XML or some other such data representation is sent. The setting I mentioned earlier is about deciding how the client will interpret this XML data.

Comment: Oh, okay. But when I change that, now it doesn't let me pass around ObservableCollections. Is there a way for me to have more than one collection type?

Comment: How would it know which collection should use which list type? Again, `List` is not sent on the wire. Only a sequence of XML elements.

Comment: I would assume there could be something in the XML that could specify?

Comment: There is nothing in the XML at all. What would a Java client do with that information?